# Serve static files for sub routes inside a Express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have everything working for normal  routes such as localhost:3000/fees and others.

[Screenshot of directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhJFy.png)

But when subroutes appear it tends to give a problem that is my static files aren't served to pages like localhost:3000/fees/cfees.
How do I serve static files to this subroutes.

I used

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

to load static files

Comment: The static file should be server based on the root directory. **How** you **load** them is quite another story! :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov How do I do it then.

Comment: You should provide some samples how you load those files on the client side.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Have edited the question take a look

Comment: How you load them on the client side, meaning the browser. Paste some code from the handlebars template.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Yes I have and it is in main.handlebars head tag. I have loaded other pages using {{{body}}}. So for loading css i use href="css/custom.css"

Comment: Using relative path means that if you open `page.com/test/` your css will be loaded from `page.com/test/css/custom.css`. That's why you either need to use absolute path (like `/css/custom.css`), which will always load everything starting from `page.com`, or use full path `page.com/css/custom.css`.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndreyPopov.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **absolute path** instead of **relative path** :

For example, use "**/bundle.js**" instead of "bundle.js"

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you want to use **bootstrap.min.css**, which is located in **c:\my_project\public\css\bootstrap.min.css** in your template file must be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

      <head>
             ...
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>

      <body>
            ...
      </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

And more to make here so in your router:

```
router.get('/fees/cfees', function(req, res) {
        res.render('cfees')
});
```

Comment: Thats wrong. It is already in fees.js route so in doing so I am going to fees/fees/cfees.

Comment: You confuse the terms. Routes and files are not the same in NodeJS. You can create any route in your router by attaching any view file to it. For example, this code will work: `router.get('/a/b/c/d', function(req, res) { res.render('fees') });` (localhost:3000/a/b/c/d) or `router.get('/fees/fees/fees/fees/cfees', function(req, res) { res.render('cfees') });` (localhost:3000/fees/fees/fees/fees/cfees)